# How do I communicate between two javascript object literals?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-slider

I want to know how I can call a method from an object within another object literal. Here is my code. I am building a jQuery UI slider. I am trying to call the **animatebox** function within the **animations** object literal and the error in my chrome console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'animateBox' of undefined
```

My code looks like this:

```
var sliderOpts = {

    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 50,
    min: 10,
    max: 100,
    step: 10,

    //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#slider-result").html(ui.value + " GB");
    },

    //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);
        var val = ui.value,
            $box = $('#message');
        switch (true) {
        case (val > 50):
            $box.animations.animateBox().html('you have chosen xtremenet');
            break;
        case (val < 50):
            $box.fadeOut().fadeIn().html('you have chosen valuenet');
            break;
        default:
            $box.fadeOut().fadeIn().html('you have chosen powernet');
        }
    }
};

var animations = {
    animateBox: function () {
        $("#message").slideDown(500);
    }
};

$(".slider").bind("slidecreate", animations.animateBox).slider(sliderOpts);
```

So how do I call this method called animateBox?

Comment: I don't get that error, and I can't imagine why you would. The code looks fine (assuming that "slider" is some plugin; maybe jQuery UI I guess).

Comment: I'm not sure about the call to animateBox in the change method in sliderOpts. I don't see how $box.animations.animateBox becomes assigned

Comment: @Pointy yes it is. Does the code look right to you? Is it possible to call a function from one object inside another object like this? Don't I have to initialize or something?

Comment: @tinyd yes. That is the problem. Can you show me the right way of doing this?

Comment: @tinyd ah yes I missed the call inside the "change" handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var animations = {
    animateBox: function (obj) {
        obj.slideDown(500);
    }
};


animations.animateBox($box.html('you have chosen xtremenet'))
```

Comment: this is very close. I had to change to $(obj).slideDown(500);
Error I am getting now is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fxqueue fx.run' in true

Comment: You could do $.fn.animateBox = function () { return this.each( function () { $(this).slideDown(500) }); };

Then $box.animateBow().html("Blah blah");

Comment: Then error could be because the definition of animations should be above slideOpts

Comment: not working man. error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { return this.each( function () { $(this).slideDown(500) }); } has no method 'html'

Comment: hey thanks Paul. I finally got that working. But a last bit is missing: I have a call that puts the whole thing together like this:     $(".slider").bind("slidecreate", animations.animateBox($('#message'))).slider(sliderOpts);

And the error I get is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

I checked my syntax on this line but I can't see the error. What is wrong here?

Comment: Hey I found the error; there was an extra semi-colon. Thanks for your help, Paul.

Answer (score 2):

`$box.animations` - is undefined  - and it is so

the element with id="message" wrapped with a jQuery object, doesn't have the animations property

in your case you can fix it by simply calling

```
animations.animateBox();
```

instead of  `$box.animations.animateBox()`

Comment: And if you make animateBox return $("#message").slideDown(500) instead of just calling it you should be able to call .html() on it

Comment: the animation may be a little bit complicated as shown by OP here (or what is the reason to create a separate object literal), but you are right the element itself could be returned for further chaining

Answer (score 1):

The jquery object $box has no .animations property.  You have defined animations as a global (window-level) variable.

Also chaining won't work because you don't return anything from the animateBox function.  I guess you want to change that function to return $('#message').  Once you have that, instead of

```
$box.animations.animateBox().html('you have chosen xtremenet');
```

try

```
animations.animateBox().html('you have chosen xtremenet');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to call `animations.animateBox()`. You haven't set it up as a jQuery method, so `$box.animations` is likely what is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could supply the animateBox function as a callback via the options. Like so:

```
var sliderOpts = {
    animateBox: function() { // magic here },
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    ...
};
```

then set the slider's animateBox value within your plugin. If you use standard plugin conventions the call to animate box in change would look like:

```
this.animateBox();
```